# How to add CSS that works only in Checkout page Mangento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.4.2, styles

I Need to add a CSS for checkout page, the css file should load only in checkout page alone it should not render for any any other pages. How should add the CSS file in the Magento 2.4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If CSS is merged then, that merged css will call in all page. Otherwise, you can add css in **checkout_index_index.xml** file :

```
<head>
        <css src="Magento_Checkout::css/customcheckout.css"/>
</head>
```

File should be available on

> **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/css/customcheckout.css**

And in css file add **.checkout-index-index** class before all css's class name. So, that css only apply on checkout page.

**Suggestion :** Instead of create css file. Add css in less file.

Answer (score 4):

Create "`checkout_index_index.xml`" file in module `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` add below code in it.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    </head>
</page>
```

Add css file in `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css`

**You can also add in theme**

Create '`css file`'

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/css/custom.css
```

Add into layout file if available already or create a new one

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Then run below commands and check:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```